# ¿Cómo obtener el texto de una función input? Python

Tags: python, funciones, input, texto

Tengo una función que recibe un texto, sin embargo me gustaría almacenar ese mismo texto en una variable pero no se como sacarlo de ahí.

```
aprender(input("Ingresa(Yo soy Lola): "))
```

**Osea que lo que se ingrese se guarde en una variable de cadena.**

```
texto_del_input=""
```

He buscado en internet y no he visto una solución a esto.

Comment: _He buscado en internet y no he visto una solución a esto_  http://letmegooglethat.com/?q=python+input ;-)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#input

Comment: Aun a riesgo de que sea un poco troll....creo que si estas aprendiendo por tu cuenta quizás "deberías" cambiar de "tutorial" o si es una asignatura volver a revisar los principios porque esta pregunta es muy básica y roza la burla. No te desanimes y sigue revisando la documentación que es muy útil y expresiva.

Comment: Estoy bastante decepcionada de mi, se supone que debía saber la respuesta, realmente es muy basica, me enfoque tanto en querer sacar el texto de la funcion que se me olvido que podria existir otra alternativa.

Comment: Para mas dudas de este tipo, te sugiero el [chat]...

Comment: Gracias, no sabia que existia un chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para guardar los datos recibidos de un input dentro de una variable

1. Debes definir la variable
2. Esta variable va a tener el input dentro

Ejemplo:

```
nombre = input("Ingresa tu nombre por favor: ")
```

Si quieres pasar ese texto que esta dentro de una variable a una función, llamas a la función y pasas la variable como parámetro.

Ejemplo:

*Defino la función saludar*

```
def saludar(parametro):
   print("hola como estas: "+parametro)
```

*Llamo la función y le paso el parámetro*

```
saludar(nombre)
```

Captura de pantalla https://prnt.sc/x7tvkm

> Nota: Mete la variable como parámetro de la función.

Comment: Hola Keysel ¿Como que meter la funcion dentro de una variable? no comprendo si lo que se ingresa en el input debe ser enviado a la funcion.

Comment: Ya entendí tu caso y modifique la respuesta obsérvala. Comenta por favor si lograste resolverlo.

Comment: Wao! gracias, era justamente lo que buscaba, ¿como no lo habia pensado?

Comment: aveces se nos olvida pensar XD